Should I switch or stay?
"Looking for advice: I've been working as a SOC Analyst in India for the past 3.5 years. I started at ₹7.5 LPA and have grown to ₹16 LPA. I'm expected to be promoted next year. Additionally, my company has offered me a path to transition into offensive security , which is a goal of mine, but it might take about two years to fully shift.
Should I stay with my current company and wait for the transition, or would it be better to start looking for opportunities elsewhere? Any advice would be appreciated.

What is your motivation behind "start looking for opportunities elsewhere?". From your description, it looks like you're on a happy path.

I have been on both sides of the fence.  At the end of the day, most employers have no loyalty towards you, unless you are truly exceptional and are regarded as a key person in the organisation.  Things mentioned now, can change.
So, as an employee you should always think of yourself first.  I think you should always be looking for better opportunities.  If you find one, then compare and decide.
There is something to be said for not changing your jobs every year as it does not look good on your CV.  But 3.5 years is a reasonable time to work for one employer, nowadays.
